# How embeded http server in own plugin on Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, http, jetty

I need an embedded http server. Which can be controlled by pressing the button (Start, Stop) in the plugin.

I looked at the jetty, but don't understand how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend [Tiny Java Web Server](http://tjws.sourceforge.net), it's pretty much as simple as it gets.

You'll find the necessary code examples under 'Embedded usage'.